# Minecraft Bukkit plugin throws Syntax Error

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to make a mixedmodeauth (my own version of an authentication plugin), but there is a problem- at the line with the star, I get the following errors:

```
Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
void is an invalid type for the variable onPlayerJoin
```

Here is my code:

```java
public class MixedPlugin extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{
    @Override
    public void onEnable(){
        getLogger().info("Mixed Mode: ON");
        getCommand("mm").setExecutor(new MixedCommand());
        
        @EventHandler
        **public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {**
            Player player = event.getPlayer();
            String name = player.getName();
            boolean isGood = getURL("http://minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=deadmau5" + name).equals("true");
            if (isGood) {
              player.sendMessage("Welcome back to server!");
            }
            else {
              List<String> ex = getConfig().getStringList("allow");
              if (((MemorySection)ex).getStringList("allow").contains(player.getName())) {
                player.sendMessage("Welcome back to server!");
                player.sendMessage("You are a few person that are using cracked minecraft and allowed to join this premium server!");
              } else {
                player.kickPlayer("Failed to login: User not premium");
              }
            }
        }
    }
    public String getURL(String url){
         Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Minecraft");
        String inputLine = "";
        try{
          URL mcheck = new URL(url);
          URLConnection mcheckc = mcheck.openConnection();
          mcheckc.setReadTimeout(1500);
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mcheckc.getInputStream()));
          inputLine = in.readLine();
          in.close();
          return inputLine;
        } catch(Exception e){
          log.warning("Error retrieving "+url+": "+e.getMessage());
        }
        return "ERROR";
      }
    @Override
    public void onDisable(){
        getLogger().info("You have disable Mixed Mode");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This isn't valid code. Java does not allow nested functions like you are currently doing(aka don't put `onPlayerJoin` inside of the `onEnable` method.

So put the method `onPlayerJoin` after `onEnable` not inside.

Example:

```
@Override
public void onEnable(){
    getLogger().info("Mixed Mode: ON");
    getCommand("mm").setExecutor(new MixedCommand());
}

@EventHandler
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    String name = player.getName();
    boolean isGood = getURL("http://minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=deadmau5" + name).equals("true");
    if (isGood) {
      player.sendMessage("Welcome back to server!");
    }
    else {
      List<String> ex = getConfig().getStringList("allow");
      if (((MemorySection)ex).getStringList("allow").contains(player.getName())) {
        player.sendMessage("Welcome back to server!");
        player.sendMessage("You are a few person that are using cracked minecraft and allowed to join this premium server!");
      } else {
        player.kickPlayer("Failed to login: User not premium");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't check for other bugs, but yes the code will still work (if it was going to work in the first place :) )

Answer (score -2):

This code has no right to work because you put the `onPlayerJoin` method in the `onEnable()` method. Instead, use:

```java
@Override
public void onEnable(){
    getLogger().info("Mixed Mode: ON");
    getCommand("mm").setExecutor(new MixedCommand());        
}
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    String name = player.getName();
    boolean isGood = getURL("http://minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=deadmau5" + name).equals("true");
    if (isGood) {
      player.sendMessage("Welcome back to server!");
    }
    else {
      List<String> ex = getConfig().getStringList("allow");
      if (((MemorySection)ex).getStringList("allow").contains(player.getName())) {
        player.sendMessage("Welcome back to server!");
        player.sendMessage("You are a few person that are using cracked minecraft and allowed to join this premium server!");
      } else {
        player.kickPlayer("Failed to login: User not premium");
      }
    }
}
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: You write the same code as the other answer on a post which is 9 years old...